# How do I get currency ratio between Binance Coin and US Dollars?

Tags: binance, swaps

I'm selling items online, and I would like to accept Binance Coin. Becaue of that I would like to know how much my item costs in Binance Coin to be able to accept offers from users using that coin.

My question is:

How can I can, with a moderate degree of security, know the conversion ratio between Binance Coin and US Dollars?

I prefer for solutions off chain for now, and, if is python or rest is even better.

Answer (score 1):

You can query BNB market price over [Coinhgecko API](https://www.coingecko.com/api/documentations/v3#/) or any other API.

Price feed services include: CoinMarketCap, Cryptocompare, Binance APIs themselves.